# Display bar chart with thumbnails in yAxis instead of label

Tags: charts, bar-chart, google-visualization, echarts

I am using two charts libraries in my project. [ECharts](https://ecomfe.github.io/echarts-doc/public/en/index.html) and [Google Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/).

I want to display bar chart with thumbnails. I need to display log of banners.

So i will need chart like below just images in axis.

[image]

I am not sure it is possible or not with any of above library.

If anyone has any ideas then please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

echarts support `rich text` as label

in the option  yAxis or xAixs -> axisLabel -> rich,

check this [example1](http://echarts.baidu.com/examples/editor.html?c=bar-rich-text)    [example2](https://ecomfe.github.io/echarts-examples/public/editor.html?c=bar-rich-text)

```
yAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    data: ['Sunny', 'Cloudy', 'Showers'],
    axisLabel: {
        formatter: function (value) {
            return '{' + value + '| }\n{value|' + value + '}';
        },
        margin: 20,
        rich: {
            value: {
                lineHeight: 30,
                align: 'center'
            },
            Sunny: {
                height: 40,
                align: 'center',
                backgroundColor: {
                    image: weatherIcons.Sunny
                }
            },
            Cloudy: {
                height: 40,
                align: 'center',
                backgroundColor: {
                    image: weatherIcons.Cloudy
                }
            },
            Showers: {
                height: 40,
                align: 'center',
                backgroundColor: {
                    image: weatherIcons.Showers
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

google charts has a method --> `getChartLayoutInterface`

this allows you to get the coordinates of various chart elements

in this case, we get the coordinates of the axis labels,
then overlay an image in its place...

```
var chartLayout = chart.getChartLayoutInterface();
var chartBounds = chartLayout.getChartAreaBoundingBox();

for (var i = 0; i < data.getNumberOfRows(); i++) {
  var axisLabelBounds = chartLayout.getBoundingBox('hAxis#0#label#' + i);
  var path = 'http://findicons.com/files/icons/512/star_wars/32/';
  var thumb = container.appendChild(document.createElement('img'));
  thumb.src = path + data.getProperty(i, 0, 'thumb');
  thumb.style.position = 'absolute';
  thumb.style.top = (axisLabelBounds.top + containerBounds.top) + 'px';
  thumb.style.left = (axisLabelBounds.left + containerBounds.left - 16) + 'px';
}
```

set the text color to transparent, so the labels are never seen...

```
hAxis: {
  textStyle: {
    color: 'transparent'
  }
}
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'X');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Y');
  data.addRows([
    [{v: 'a', p: {thumb: 'clone_old.png'}}, 20],
    [{v: 'b', p: {thumb: 'boba_fett.png'}}, 15],
    [{v: 'c', p: {thumb: 'jango_fett.png'}}, 30],
    [{v: 'd', p: {thumb: 'clone_3.png'}}, 5],
    [{v: 'e', p: {thumb: 'clone_2.png'}}, 25]
  ]);

  var options = {
    legend: 'none',
    hAxis: {
      textStyle: {
        color: 'transparent'
      }
    }
  };

  var container = document.getElementById('chart_div');
  var containerBounds = container.getBoundingClientRect();
  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(container);

  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
    var chartLayout = chart.getChartLayoutInterface();
    var chartBounds = chartLayout.getChartAreaBoundingBox();

    for (var i = 0; i < data.getNumberOfRows(); i++) {
      var axisLabelBounds = chartLayout.getBoundingBox('hAxis#0#label#' + i);
      var path = 'http://findicons.com/files/icons/512/star_wars/32/';
      var thumb = container.appendChild(document.createElement('img'));
      thumb.src = path + data.getProperty(i, 0, 'thumb');
      thumb.style.position = 'absolute';
      thumb.style.top = (axisLabelBounds.top + containerBounds.top) + 'px';
      thumb.style.left = (axisLabelBounds.left + containerBounds.left - 16) + 'px';
    }
  });

  chart.draw(data, options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: This save me for another problem, thanks.. The key is `getBoundingBox` function